# Got a task with String operations. matcher.find() throws outOfBoundExc, matcher.find(0) works fine... why is that?

Tags: java, string, matcher

task is to delete letters i from sentence.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int index = 8;
    String letter = "i";
    String text = "method appends the string to the end. t is overloaded to have the following forms.";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(text);
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(letter);
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(sb);

   //while (mat.find()) -throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. 
    while (mat.find(0)){
        sb.deleteCharAt(mat.start());
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

well, program works, but I dont understand why obvious method doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `mat.reset()` method, as when you are deleting the char the length of the string that matcher knows of becomes invalid and you will have to reset the matcher for that.

What happens is as follows: You create the matcher and pass it the string whose original length was suppose 5, now after calling `find`, you are deleting a character from the buffer, which invalidates the state of matcher as the new length would be 4. So a reset is necessary.

> Why `find(0)` works?

Answer to that lies in the source,

Method from JDK 1.6,

```
public boolean find(int start) {
        int limit = getTextLength();
        if ((start < 0) || (start > limit))
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Illegal start index");

        reset(); //reset is called here
        return search(start);
}
```

Comment: I have provided the reasoning behind why find(0) works and why find() does not.